# Space of Gaussian Functions is Closed in $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution

Let $\Omega, \mu$ be a probability space.  A measurable function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called Gaussian if $$\mu (f^{-1}(A))=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}\int_Ae^{-x^2/2\sigma ^2} dx$$ for some $\sigma>0$. I'm reading a proof that the space of Guassian functions is closed in $L^2(\Omega)$.  The proof goes as follows:

If $f_n \in L^2(\Omega)$ is a sequence converging (in the $L^2$ norm) to $f$, then since $\sigma_n^2= ||f_n||_2^2$, we have $\sigma_n \rightarrow \sigma$.  Therefore, for every $g(x)\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, we have

$$\lim_n \frac{1}{\sigma_n \sqrt{2\pi }}\int e^{-x^2/2\sigma_n ^2} g(x) dx=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}\int e^{-x^2/2\sigma ^2} g(x)dx$$ (I guess this is by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem?).  Then the author says "This shows that the distribution of $f$ (i.e. the measure $A \mapsto \mu(f^{-1}(A))$) is the measure $\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-x^2/2\sigma ^2}dx$."

How does this last line follow?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_n \sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-x^2/2\sigma_n^2} g(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2} g(x) \, dx$$

shows that $\mu(f_n^{-1}(\cdot))$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. On the other hand, by assumption, $f_n$ converges in $L^2$ to $f$ and this implies in particular convergence in distribution, i.e. $\mu(f_n^{-1}(\cdot)) \stackrel{d}{\to} \mu(f^{-1}(\cdot))$. Hence, $\mu(f^{-1}(\cdot)) \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @Timkinsella It follows directly from the Markov inequality that $$\mu(|f_n-f|>\varepsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \int |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 \, d\mu(x)$$ This shows that $L^2$-convergence implies convergence in probability. And since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, this proves the claim.

Comment: ah ok. thanks. so i guess what i was missing was the fact that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ implies "convergence in distribution".  Could I trouble you for a proof of that if its short?  Also, this doesn't seem to be the actual definition but can I just take "convergence in measure" to mean $\mu_n (A) \rightarrow \mu (A)$ for all measurable $A\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Timkinsella No, convergence in measure does *not* mean $\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)$ for all measurable $A$ - that's simply not the correct definition.

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'm not used to probability language.  thanks for your help!  I'll accept your answer after I look up what all these terms mean and piece everything together :)

Comment: @Timkinsella Well, the problem is that "convergence in measure" can mean both "convergence in distribution" and "convergence in probability"...depends on the author.

Comment: oh! sorry i meant "convergence in distribution."  I know what convergence in *measure* means. Anyway, I should be good once I decipher some of this crazy jargon you folks use :)

Comment: Hi @saz  One more question if you have time:  Your argument doesn't really seem to make use of the equation $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_n \sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-x^2/2\sigma_n^2} g(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2} g(x) \, dx$$ because, as you say, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$, then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in probability, and therefore $f_n \rightarrow f$ in distribution.  Therefore $\lim_n \frac{1}{\sigma_n \sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-x^2/2\sigma_n ^2}= \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-x^2/2\sigma ^2}$ is the distribution of $f$ (where $\sigma = ||f||_2$), right?

Comment: @Timkinsella No; I make use of the equation in order to see that $\mu(f_n^{-1})$ converges in distribution to a normal distribution with variance $\sigma^2$. In general, you cannot conclude from the convergence of the densities that the functions converge in distribution.

Comment: ugh, I think I've mixed up "density" and "distribution."  The text i'm reading doesn't seem to make a distinction, which is puzzling.

Comment: So what exactly do you mean by "$\mu (f_n^{-1})$ converges in distribution".  I read a definition of convergence in distribution for a sequence of *functions* (the distribution functions converge pointwise wherever F is continuous), but I don't know what it means for measures.

Comment: ah! you must mean "weak convergence of measures" since I just read that thats equivalent to convergence in distribution. Ok I will try to stop spamming you now.

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, exactly. Usually, the convergence of functions (actually, I would call them random variables) is usually *by definition* equivalent to the (weak) convergence of the corresponding distributions.